# combine two oracle sql results into single dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two selects and I want to combine them in such a way, that only one row that has key column matched in both selects are returned(one row in first select and one row in 2nd select). Is there any built-in way in Oracle 10g to achieve this?

I have two sql as below

Query 1:

select c11, c12 from table t1
where c11=1000

Query 2:
select c21, c22
from t2
where c21=1000

I want to combine both query 1 and query 2 on key columns(OPTYREVN_OPTY_XI, OPTYREVN_SEGMENT_XI and OPTYREVN_OPTYREVNCRM_ID). My output should contain only the only one row which found in results of query 1 and query 2.

I am not sure to use UNION or Intersect or left outer join.
Kindly suggest me some solution which will be helpful in this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `t3` or why you are doing a cartesian join between `t1` and `t3` ... can you please clarify?

Comment: i just show that my first query is combination of t1 and t3 using key columns, not cartesian join. sorry for confusion in my question.

Comment: @user1468031 Let me ask you if I understand correctly... Do you want the results from the 2 queries (5 columns total) to be in one row?

Or do you want to return the value, if it is in both queries ? c1 and c21 (as example)

Comment: @Raphael, i currently use 2 sql queries in informatica as source queries. query uses 3 tables to get one result with three columns. 2nd query fetch result with three key column. I want to use 2nd query result and combine with first query result using those three column as inner join or any specific oracle function available to use?

Comment: @user1468031 You should definetly post an example of what you want,
if you want to have the 2 queries in one line, why not use a sub-query ?

Comment: `WHERE     TRUNC (TDDAY.DAY_DT) >= TRUNC (OPTY_JOB_START_DT)
       AND TRUNC (TDDAY.DAY_DT) <= (OPTY_JOB_END_DT)` is a bad idea unless you have a function-based index on `TDDAY.DAY_DT`.

Answer (score 0):

So, If I got you right, you want to have c1 , c2 , c33 , c21 , c22 and c 23 on one line, if both queries return only one line and no information can link them, this should work...

```
SELECT a.* , b.* 
FROM (select c1, c2, c33
   from t1, t3
   where c1= 1000 and c33 is null) a ,  
   (select c21, c22, c23
   from t2
   where c21= 1000) b
/*WHERE...*/  --you could always use some condition linking a and b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use a join:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c33, c21, c22, c23
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t3 ON <key columns>
 INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.c1 = t2.c21
 WHERE t1.c1 = 1000
   AND t3.c33 IS NULL;
```